# how to use a generated value for a field in a dependent object?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I am using JPA to store my objects in the database. I have a User class that has as a field (One to One relationship) a Password class. When a new user registers I want the generated Id for the User class to also be the id field for the Password class. Any ideas on how to go about this? Here is the relevant code...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE,generator="user_id_seq")
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private Password password;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="passwords")
public class Password {
    @Id
  //@GeneratedValue ???
    @Column(name="user_id")
    int userId;

    @Column(name="password")
    String password;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `Password` a direct reference to its parent `User` and mark that field as your id:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="passwords")
public class Password {
  @Id
  User user;
  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you still want the primitive `userId` field, use [`@MapsId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="passwords")
public class Password {
  @Id
  int userId;

  @MapsId
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  User user;
  // ...
}
```